# Got error during make a setup for win app using VS 2012

Tags: c#, installation, winapp

After finishing my C# application I had to make an installer.
When i want to choose SQL Express in prerequisites section this error appear :

> "Error    3   To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as
>   my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download
>   file 'SqlExpress2008R2\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.EXE' for item 'SQL Server
>   2008 R2 Express' to your local machine. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=239883."

I use installer extenssion for Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Did you try... doing what the message tells you... and downloading that file?

Comment: I have the problem even though I have the file...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, even though the files were in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2008R2` directory.

This worked for me - not sure if it's the "correct" solution but it did the job:

I copied the two files `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` and `SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` into the `\en` subdirectory within the above path.

`en` was the only subdirectory unlike some of the other packages. I imagine it would be a different language code depending on your local culture, or there could possibly more than one?

I have Windows 7 Professional with Visual Studio 2013 (in case that info is relevant...)

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\SqlExpress2012\en
```

For vs 2019 try to copy the setup files in the above folder(en) too.